# Hadoop commands are taking a very long time to return

Tags: linux, centos, hadoop, hdfs

I am logged in (via SSH) to the NameNode of my Hadoop cluster; the problem I am having is that any `hadoop fs` commands, even simple ones like `hadoop fs -ls` are completed quickly, but take many minutes to return control of the shell to the user. For instance, `hadoop fs -ls` prints the directory listing immediately, but the next bash prompt does not appear for nearly ten minutes. If I type `hadoop fs -mkdir` there is no output, but if I then open a new SSH session and type `hadoop fs -ls` I will see the directory in the path (of course, I will not be able to use either shell for a while after that).

I am running vanilla Hadoop on CentOS 6.2; I have eight nodes. If you need further information, please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the namenode log. A more low-level approach would be to run `strace hadoop fs -ls`.